# Change file permission not working in wordpress dockerfile

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to change the user: root to www-data in Dockerfile to build wordpress image. Once I run the dockerfile and go inside the image: the permission is not changed.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:php7.1-apache
COPY . /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
```

This is the result in the image by running that Dockerfie:

```
root@081507c3824e:/var/www/html# ls -lh
total 228K
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  149 Jul  5 05:09 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  405 Jul  5 05:09 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  20K Jul  5 05:09 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 7.2K Jul  5 05:09 readme.html
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4.0K Jul  5 05:15 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  351 Jul  5 05:09 wp-blog-header.php
```

Comment: Update: I tried to overwrite the docker-entrypoint.sh by adding the chown line at the start of the sh file but still faced  these kind of errors: "$1 inbound variable not found, require EOF"

Answer (score 0):

`/var/www/html` is marked a `VOLUME` in [Dockerfile of wordpress](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/def14e3e6e6a376dcfb856f9eb542e3e399457af/php7.2/apache/Dockerfile#L115). Your RUN instruction won't persist after the build.

You can try any of the following approaches if you want to change the permisions of `/var/www/html/` directory.

1. You can mount a directory with modified permissions from host machine into the container.
2. You can create an entrypoint script which changes the permission of the directory before starting the main process.

Comment: I will try with the first option : it means i need to add in volumes:..... in dockerfile, correct? Sorry that i am still new to Docker.

Comment: How are you starting the container? Using docker-compose or `docke run`?

Comment: hi, can you please explain detail about the option 1 please. I can't still solve it now